# Database not found error when i try to connect netbeans into built in java db?

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans, derby

i followed [this](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html) tutorial to set up a connection to Java DB database in NetBeans IDE.But i am getting database not found error.
 Here is the snap shoot of the java program.

[image]

And here is the snap shoot of the database

[image]

And here is the snap shoot of the error message

[image]

Comment: `jdbc:derby:what` is a relative reference to the embedded database stored in the folder named `what` relative to your current working directory, which probably isn't accessing the database named `what` because the current working directory isn't what you think it is.

Comment: The database is stored in C:\Users\The\.netbeans-derby\what  then i change the URL to this  URL="jdbc:derby:C:\Users\The\.netbeans-derby\what" but the same error.

Comment: Perhaps the root cause of the exception is different than you think it is. Try  getting to the root cause using this technique: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: Please post the code and exception as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

Change your database connection line

Connection conn =
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:what");

Comment: The problem is not on that.The" what" and "what" are the user name and password of the database.